# Where to start summation from

Tags: probability, expectation

Question: (a)For X∼Pois(λ), Find E(5X).

Do we sum from 0 or 1?

Comment: Sum what from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! It's helpful to include more context in your question such as things you have tried and ideas you have. For more on asking good questions, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also see [the linearity of expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/)

Answer (score 1):

A Poisson random variable can be intuitively interpreted as the number of occurrences of something in a given interval, so it can take on $0$. A geometric random variable is intuitively the number of times before we get the first "success" in a sequence of Bernoulli trials, so it can also take on $0$ (think about that you get "success" at the first trial, so there is $0$ fails.). Hence the range of both types of random variables is $\{ 0, 1, \dots \}$.

Comment: @CheggKidd, Yes some authors do make it $1$. It is about technicalities, which I guess you are not worried about at this stage:). You should follow the book your instructor use; see how the author defines the geometric distribution.